# Не понятна логика строки, где self участвует в операторе присваивания

Tags: python, flask

```
def init_app(self, app, add_context_processor=True):
    '''
    Configures an application. This registers an `after_request` call, and
    attaches this `LoginManager` to it as `app.login_manager`.
     :param app: The :class:`flask.Flask` object to configure
    :type app: :class:`flask.Flask`
    :param add_context_processor: Whether to add a context processor to
                                  the app that adds a `current_user` 
                                  variable to the template.
                                  Defaults to ``True
    :type add_context_processor: bool
    '''
    app.login_manager = self
    app.after_request(self._update_remember_cookie)

    self._login_disabled = app.config.get('LOGIN_DISABLED', False)

    if add_context_processor:
        app.context_processor(_user_context_processor)
```

Не понятна cтрочка `app.login_manager = self`, а именно присвоение `self`. Обычно `self` находится в методе, как параметр. Логика этой строки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self` - не более чем переменная. Обычно она хранит указатель на инстанс класса, т.е. конкретный созданный объект с этого класса ( например: класс Кошка, инстанс - Мурка )

В указанном примере - указатель одного класса передается другому. Дабы это было чуть-более наглядно:

```
class A:

  def __init__(self):
    self.test = 'Hello from A'

  def init(self, app):
    # Меняем в заданном аргументе атрибут manager на указатель инстанса
    app.manager = self

class B:

  def __init__(self):
    self.test = 'Hello from B'
    self.manager = None

  def print_test_vars(self):
    print(self.test)
    if self.manager is not None:
      print(self.manager)
      print(self.manager.test)
    print('******')

a = A()  # a - инстанс класса A
b = B()  # b - инстанс класса B


b.print_test_vars()
# Выведет в консоль: 
# Hello from B
# ******
a.init(b)

b.print_test_vars()
# Выведет в консоль: 
# Hello from B
# <A object at 0x7f1875eb8320>
# Hello from A
# ******
```

Т.е. в конечном итоге смысл строки сводится к тому, что бы одному классу передать инстанс текущего класса. По сути, это практически тоже самое, что и:

```
manager = LoginManager()
app.manager = manager
```

Comment: Мне кажется, автору было интересно не "как", а "зачем"

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n ну, объяснив "как", может стать понятно "зачем". Если прям уж совсем нужно точно знать "зачем" - нужно смотреть исходники flask. Но из приведенного кода - я сделал вывод что `self` - это какой-то менеджер сессий, который биндит себя к инстансу `app` фласка

Comment: Тут, как мне объясняли, "если поняли Вы, не значит, что поймут другие". Лучше дать прямой ответ.

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n к слову, там в docstring описано, что передается в качестве аргументов, я это как-то упустил из виду. Но мой вывод оказался верен